# Nodejs intercept function logs

Tags: node.js, logging, stdout

I want to intercept a function output to stdout, for example store it in a file or keep it in a variable.

```
function theFunctionToInterceptLogs() {
     setTimeOut(function () {
         console.log('this should be intercepted');
     }, 1000);
}

console.log('this should not be intercepted');

theFunctionToInterceptLogs();

console.log('this also should not be intercepted');
```

Note that the function in question run asynchronously.

I thought about executing the function in a child process while redirecting its stdout to a file but I don't know how to do that.

Any idea?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Just replace all of your `console.log()` calls with some sort of other logging function.  Also, check out Winston...  great library for handling logs.

Comment: @Brad well the function is from another library, so I can not edit its code.